# Access array of object using Object.keys() and map() method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures, mapreduce

How can I access an array of objects which is structured like below? I want to build a tree of this to output the data like the `languages` object in the array and also its nested objects as well using `Object.keys()` and `map()`.

Basically I want to loop through each of the objects and access the `languages` object inside it.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
var productMap2 = {};

 productMap2 = Object.keys(jsonData[0]).map(function(key) {
                  return jsonData[0][key];
                });
```

Here is my JSON:

```
   var jsonData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "project_name": "Project101-updated TODAY",
        "created_by": "John Doe",
        "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
        "created_date": "2018-01-09T15:49:54Z",
        "updated_date": "2018-01-09T15:49:54Z",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "language": "English",
                "created_by": "John Doe",
                "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:45:54Z",
                "beta_project": 1,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "phase_name": "Phase1",
                        "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
                        "created_by": "John Doe",
                        "phase_title": "Title",
                        "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
                        "segment": "Consumer",
                        "locale": "English",
                        "is_published": false,
                        "beta_start_date": "1975-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "beta_end_date": "1975-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "project_owner": "John Doe",
                        "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
                        "last_update_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
                        "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
                        "last_published_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
                        "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
                        "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
                        "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
                        "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
                        "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
                        "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
                        "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
                        "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
                        "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
                        "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
                        "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
                        "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
                        "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
                        "beta_language": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "phase_name": "Phase2",
                        "created_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                        "created_by": "John Doe",
                        "phase_title": "Title",
                        "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
                        "segment": "Consumer",
                        "locale": "English",
                        "is_published": false,
                        "beta_start_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "beta_end_date": "2018-10-20T00:00:00Z",
                        "project_owner": "John Doe",
                        "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
                        "last_update_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                        "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
                        "last_published_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                        "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
                        "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
                        "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
                        "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
                        "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
                        "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
                        "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
                        "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
                        "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
                        "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
                        "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
                        "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
                        "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
                        "beta_language": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "language": "Japanese",
                "created_by": "John Doe",
                "created_date": "2018-01-09T01:35:23.743333Z",
                "beta_project": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "project_name": "Project102-updated",
        "created_by": "Sammy Sosa",
        "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
        "created_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
        "updated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "language": "Traditional Chines",
                "created_by": "John Doe",
                "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:46:16Z",
                "beta_project": 2,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "phase_name": "Phase3",
                        "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
                        "created_by": "John Doe",
                        "phase_title": "Title",
                        "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
                        "segment": "Consumer",
                        "locale": "English",
                        "is_published": false,
                        "beta_start_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                        "beta_end_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "project_owner": "John Doe",
                        "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
                        "last_update_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
                        "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
                        "last_published_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
                        "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
                        "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
                        "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
                        "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
                        "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
                        "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
                        "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
                        "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
                        "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
                        "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
                        "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
                        "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
                        "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
                        "beta_language": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "project_name": "Project103-updated",
        "created_by": "JOHN doe",
        "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
        "ceated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
        "updated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "languages": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "language": "Simplified Chines",
                "created_by": "John Doe",
                "created_date": "2018-01-09T01:34:26.240000Z",
                "beta_project": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've just loop over it, like this 
for(var i in jsonData){
    var key = i;
    var val = jsonData[i];
    for(var j in val){
        var sub_key = j;
        var sub_val = val[j];
        console.log(sub_key);
    }
}

Comment: ok, please add the expected output and your attempt to the question itself.

Comment: What is "too much looping"?

Comment: I've just edited my question. thank you for the replies

Comment: The expected output would really help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a very good tool, both handy and powerful, for such a task ...

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "project_name": "Project101-updated TODAY",
  "created_by": "John Doe",
  "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
  "created_date": "2018-01-09T15:49:54Z",
  "updated_date": "2018-01-09T15:49:54Z",
  "is_deleted": false,
  "languages": [{
    "id": 1,
    "language": "English",
    "created_by": "John Doe",
    "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:45:54Z",
    "beta_project": 1,
    "details": [{
      "id": 1,
      "phase_name": "Phase1",
      "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
      "created_by": "John Doe",
      "phase_title": "Title",
      "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
      "segment": "Consumer",
      "locale": "English",
      "is_published": false,
      "beta_start_date": "1975-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "beta_end_date": "1975-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "project_owner": "John Doe",
      "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
      "last_update_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
      "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
      "last_published_date": "2018-01-04T04:33:00Z",
      "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
      "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
      "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
      "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
      "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
      "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
      "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
      "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
      "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
      "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
      "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
      "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
      "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
      "beta_language": 1
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "phase_name": "Phase2",
      "created_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
      "created_by": "John Doe",
      "phase_title": "Title",
      "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
      "segment": "Consumer",
      "locale": "English",
      "is_published": false,
      "beta_start_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "beta_end_date": "2018-10-20T00:00:00Z",
      "project_owner": "John Doe",
      "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
      "last_update_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
      "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
      "last_published_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
      "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
      "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
      "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
      "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
      "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
      "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
      "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
      "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
      "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
      "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
      "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
      "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
      "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
      "beta_language": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "language": "Japanese",
    "created_by": "John Doe",
    "created_date": "2018-01-09T01:35:23.743333Z",
    "beta_project": 1
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "project_name": "Project102-updated",
  "created_by": "Sammy Sosa",
  "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
  "created_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
  "updated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
  "is_deleted": false,
  "languages": [{
    "id": 2,
    "language": "Traditional Chines",
    "created_by": "John Doe",
    "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:46:16Z",
    "beta_project": 2,
    "details": [{
      "id": 4,
      "phase_name": "Phase3",
      "created_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
      "created_by": "John Doe",
      "phase_title": "Title",
      "external_url": "https://wwww.nba.com",
      "segment": "Consumer",
      "locale": "English",
      "is_published": false,
      "beta_start_date": "2010-10-10T00:00:00Z",
      "beta_end_date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "project_owner": "John Doe",
      "project_subtitutes": "Gello Tupac",
      "last_update_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
      "last_updated_by": "John Doe",
      "last_published_date": "2018-01-04T04:37:13Z",
      "last_published_by": "Neil Armstrong",
      "accrdn_title_one": "title one",
      "accrdn_contents_one": "content one",
      "accrdn_title_two": "title two",
      "accrdn_contents_two": "content two",
      "accrdn_title_three": "title three",
      "accrdn_contents_three": "content three",
      "accrdn_title_four": "titile four",
      "accrdn_contents_four": "content four",
      "accrdn_title_five": "title five",
      "accrdn_contents_five": "content five",
      "accrdn_title_six": "title six",
      "accrdn_contents_six": "content six",
      "beta_language": 2
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "project_name": "Project103-updated",
  "created_by": "JOHN doe",
  "updated_by": "Wes Smith",
  "ceated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
  "updated_date": "2018-01-05T03:13:08Z",
  "is_deleted": false,
  "languages": [{
    "id": 3,
    "language": "Simplified Chines",
    "created_by": "John Doe",
    "created_date": "2018-01-09T01:34:26.240000Z",
    "beta_project": 10
  }]
}];


function collectLanguageItemFromProjectList (collector, projectItem) {
  var
    languageMap   = collector.map;
    languageList  = collector.list;

  projectItem.languages.forEach(function (languageItem) {
    if (!(languageItem.language in languageMap)) {  // registry lookup.

      languageMap[languageItem.language] = true;    // registry update.
      languageList.push(languageItem);
    }
  });
  return collector;
}


var languageList = jsonData.reduce(collectLanguageItemFromProjectList, {

  map : {},
  list: []

}).list;


console.log('languageList : ', languageList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. is it also possible to also show the details object array inside of the languages objects because it shows []object] as result

Comment: @JohnWick ... the function collects any `language` object from a given list of, what I assume(d), `Project` items. It does so by pushing any matching reference into an array. It tries to prevent duplicates by distinguishing `language` objects each by it's `language` attribute value. The final `languageList` contains unique `language` item references each of it being a substructure of it's related (parent) `Project` item. Thus each listed `language` item is fully equipped, including a `details` property in case the referred structure does feature it.

Comment: @JohnWick ...  what you see as `[object]` might be due to the environment your are logging the final list to. If one presses the "Run code snippet" button of the above provided example code one gets a complete log of all the features as they were provided by the original `jsonData` object. Thus one does see `details` twice. First for `"language": "English"` and second for `"language": "Traditional Chines"`.

Comment: ah yes you're right Peter, I've put it now in Atom and I can see it now, so I can loop also in all of them right, so I can see the whole JSON data? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Building a tree is definitely a recursive task. However your structure has arrays in it, so if you try and draw your structure on paper, naming each part, your array's elements will have either no names, or they will have numbers for it.
What I would do is give each array element a name depending on the array value name (example if you have the "languages" array, pick the "language" attribute from the object, and on "details" pick "phase_name") and use that in your tree.
The solution code itself depends on the expected tree structure. It seems logical to define a structure like this:
`TreeNode{
  'name': string,
  'value': string, //null if it has children
  'children': [TreeNode], //null if it has value
  'expanded': boolean //irrelevant if it has value
}`
I have done this before at my previous workplace and I used two recursive functions that returned the converted structure (one for objects and one for arrays) but I had a different structure for the array. Here it is good enough to determine the value type to the object key and call the recursive function for each element and create a child for it.